# Why does this Slick test inconsistently fail?

Tags: scala, slick

I am coding the simple getting started (http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.1/gettingstarted.html) examples from Slick 3.1.1 documentation.

I wrote the following test to assert on the count of coffees:

```scala
@Test def countCoffees() = {

    // Read all coffees and print them to the console
    val rf = db.run(coffees.result)
    // Equivalent SQL code:
    // select COF_NAME, SUP_ID, PRICE, SALES, TOTAL from COFFEES

    val r = Await.result(rf, Duration.Inf)

    assert(r.size == 5)
  }
```

Some times the test pass and other times the result is the following:

```sh
[info] - countCoffees *** FAILED ***
[info]   org.scalatest.junit.JUnitTestFailedError: Vector() had size 0 instead of expected size 5 (Test.scala:40)
```

The TestSuite is defined as follows:

```
class SlickScalaEjemplo extends FunSuite with SchemaEjemplo
```

Being `SchemaEjemplo` as follows

```scala
trait SchemaEjemplo extends FunSuite with SlickBase with BeforeAndAfter {

  val setup = DBIO.seq(
    // Create the tables, including primary and foreign keys
    (suppliers.schema ++ coffees.schema).create,

    // Insert some suppliers
    suppliers += (101, "Acme, Inc.", "99 Market Street", "Groundsville", "CA", "95199"),
    suppliers += (49, "Superior Coffee", "1 Party Place", "Mendocino", "CA", "95460"),
    suppliers += (150, "The High Ground", "100 Coffee Lane", "Meadows", "CA", "93966"),
    // Equivalent SQL code:
    // insert into SUPPLIERS(SUP_ID, SUP_NAME, STREET, CITY, STATE, ZIP) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)

    // Insert some coffees (using JDBC's batch insert feature, if supported by the DB)
    coffees ++= Seq(
      ("Colombian", 101, 7.99, 0, 0),
      ("French_Roast", 49, 8.99, 0, 0),
      ("Espresso", 150, 9.99, 0, 0),
      ("Colombian_Decaf", 101, 8.99, 0, 0),
      ("French_Roast_Decaf", 49, 9.99, 0, 0)
    )
  // Equivalent SQL code:
  // insert into COFFEES(COF_NAME, SUP_ID, PRICE, SALES, TOTAL) values (?,?,?,?,?)
  )

  val setupFuture = db.run(setup)

  after {
    db.close()
  }

}
```

**Why does the Await on this test don't work properly?**

Comment: There isn't anywhere near enough information here to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was not waiting for the following

```
val setupFuture = db.run(setup)
```

to execute so the tests were running without expecting the schema to be created or  completed.

I changed the tests as follows:

```
  test("countCoffees") {

    setupFuture.map(x => {
      // Read all coffees and print them to the console
      val rf = db.run(coffees.result)
      // Equivalent SQL code:
      // select COF_NAME, SUP_ID, PRICE, SALES, TOTAL from COFFEES

      val r = Await.result(rf, Duration.Inf)

      assert(r.size == 5)
    })

  }
```

So the execution of the different `Action` with `db.run` are executed on a complete schema and now the tests are all green.